# Restart Applescript causing infinite reboot loop

Tags: loops, applescript, restart, infinite

I tried to set up Voice Control to restart my mac by running the applescript:

tell application "System Events"

restart

end tell

I set it up for voice control. I'd say "Restart the Mac"

However this put my mac into an infinite restart loop!

Had to trash the script.

Is there a solution to this problem with a different applescript that doesn't go into a loop? It would be great to simply say "Restart the Mac" and then presto it restarts.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Voice Control** every day, without error, to restart my computer.

These are the steps I took.

Paste this following **AppleScript** code into a new **Script Editor** document and save it as "Restart Computer.scpt" (Don't save it to any "Startup Items" Folder)

```
tell application "System Events" to restart
```

Make sure you grant access in System Preferences for System Events.app to be allowed to control your computer.

With **Voice Control** currently active, select the new "Restart Computer.scpt" file in **Finder**, then speak the command "Make This Speakable".

You Should then see a pop-up window like this...

[image]

Just insert the voice command you want to use (I use "Restart Computer") and click Save.

*Note: Before doing all of this, you should remove any previous custom commands you have set for restarting the computer, from your Commands list in System Preferences.*

*As an added bonus, this following AppleScript code will reveal the file which stores all of your custom voice commands, in Finder.  It's  a good idea to backup this file from time to time. Also copying this file to a different computer will allow you to use the custom commands on that computer.*

```
set customDictationCommands to (path to preferences folder as text) & ¬
    "com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.CustomCommands.plist"

tell application "Finder" to reveal alias customDictationCommands
```

Comment: Ah Victory; got it to work in Ventura ;-) Thanks wch1zpink

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: a Ventura buggy system preference window; could not reach System Events to enable. So an scpt file works fine; but an application file would send things into an infinite loop. That was my previous problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AppleScript is the best tool for this. In `System Preferences→Accessibility→Voice Control` you can enable Apple's built-in voice command system, which should work out-of-the-box. They don't have a built-in Restart command so you'll have to create one, but that's easy enough. Click the 'Commands...' button at the bottom right, then click the '+' button at the bottom left, and you can choose any of several ways of implementing it.

Comment: I tried a menu item; "Restart..." but that didn't work. Tried keyboard commands; but they wont enter into the text field for restart. Currently just using Alfred "R" to restart; but would like to do it with voice.

Comment: @zebonautsmith: check wch1zpink's post above.  I was going to do the same and edit into my post, but no sense duplicating good work.

Answer (score 0):

With  **restarting script saved as application** the simple **restart** command will enter into infinite reboot loop. This is because of unsaved state of application.

To solve this problem, use following script application instead:

```
tell application "System Events" to restart with state saving preference
```